# Getting an average value of toner consumption per day

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a script that check my printer levels every x minutes. I get that data inserted into an T-SQL table.

The table looks somewhat like this:

```
Toner Level  Date Time
50           1.7.2017 20:10
45           1.7.2017 20:25
42           1.7.2017 20:39
36           1.7.2017 20:53
24           1.7.2017 21:08
22           1.7.2017 21:22
21           1.7.2017 21:37
19           1.7.2017 21:51
15           1.7.2017 22:05
9            2.7.2017 17:46
```

1. I'm trying to think of a query that would give me an average toner consumption per day based on the values. 
   To get this done, I was trying to use excel and then get the difference between each subsequent value to get the difference in another column and then get an average of that, but I'm not happy with this solution. I'm kinda sure there is something simpler, but I cannot seem to find it.

Wanted Result

```
AVG(TonerConsumption)   DateTime
4.55558           1.7.2017
```

2. Does anyone have an idea how I would deal with eventual refills and when the value goes back to 100? Do I need to introduce another column that would "somehow" count the refills (like checking the toner ID for example if possible, or before inserting into the table checking whether the new value is greater than the latest one and then giving that specific column an increased value?

Example:

```
Toner Level  Date Time
9            2.7.2017 06:10
5            2.7.2017 14:20
1            2.7.2017 16:20
100          2.7.2017 16:35
```

Struggling really hard to make progress, so I'd appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.  In addition, decide if you want a solution in excel or t-sql, and choose the appropriate tag.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Done. Hopefully OK. (need tsql)

Comment: What is your plan for handling the lack of midnight samples? Prorate the consumption across the time span that crosses a day boundary? Charge it all to the first or second date? How about refills? If you go from `42` to `93` you can assume that a refill occurred and that the level went to `100`, but what do you use for the pre-refill level? All you know is that it was not more than `42` (unless you missed one or more intervening refills).

Comment: @HABO The timestamp occurs every 5 minutes. I just gave a smaller sample situation.

Comment: Five minute samples will always hit midnight and minimum levels/refills perfectly! Please ignore the issues I raised.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the refills using cumulative sums to identify groups:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when toner_level = 100 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by datetime) as cartridgegroup
from t;
```

The only issue you might have is if someone inserts a new cartridge and then doesn't use it before the next time period check.  That is something of an edge case, and you would need to much better describe what you want done in edge cases.  This assumes -- as your question states -- that the value goes to 100 for a new Cartridge.

If you want the average amount per day:

```
select cast(datetime as date), avg(toner_level)
from t
group by cast(datetime as date)
order by cast(datetime as date);
```

Comment: I will check this asap.